# how to compute the homology groups of graphs?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

how should I compute the homology groups of graphs for example the homology groups of $K5$ ?
is it related to the genus of the graph?

Comment: The definition can be given [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology#Definition). For a graph, using the notation in the link, you get $C_0=H_0(X_0,X_{-1})=\mathbb{Z}^{|V|}$, where $V$ are the vertices, $C_1=H_1(X_1,X_0)=\mathbb{Z}^{|E|}$, where $E$ are the edges, and all other groups are trivial. Then the map from $C_1\to C_0$ sends the generator in $C_1$ corresponding to the edge $e$ to the difference of the generators in $C_0$ corresponding to the vertices that the edge joins. The homology groups of the chain are the homology groups of the graph.

Comment: A simplifying step is to first compute a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) of each connected component, collapse the tree, and then compute the cellular homology for the resulting graph. After the collapse, each connected component will have only one vertex with many loops on it, one loop for each edge of the connected component no in the spanning tree.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite graph $G$ is a $1$-complex, so its $H_n$ vanish for $n\ge2$.
If it is connected then $H_0(G,\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z$. Then it is homotopy
equivalent to a bouquet of circles, so $H_1(G,\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z^a$
for some $a$. Its Euler characteristic is $1-a$, and that equals $v-e$
where $v$ and $e$ are the number of vertices and edges, respectively.

For non-connected graphs, you could compute the homology of each component.

Comment: To determine $a$, compute a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) for the connected component and count the edges not in the tree.

Comment: for $k5$ its $Z^6$ also the fundamental group of $K5$ is  $Z^6$. is the fundamental group in graphs always equal to first homology group?

Comment: @user297564 For $K5$, which is connected, you can take a spanning tree the tree formed by one vertex and all the edges coming out of it. Then there are $10-4=6$ edges of the graph not in the spanning tree.

Comment: @user297564 The fundamental group is not $\mathbb{Z}^6$, its [Abelianization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Abelianization.html) is. The fundamental group would be the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) with $6$ generators

Comment: oh yes, thanks alot.